# pyspatialite, cannot update geometry

Tags: python, spatialite, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to update geometry column with pyspatialite but it returns error:

> spatialite.dbapi2.IntegrityError: mypoints.the_geom violates Geometry constraint   [geom-type or SRID not allowed]

My code is:

```
 cursor.execute(''' UPDATE mypoints SET  address = ?, the_geom = geomFromText('POINT(%f %f)', 2100)  WHERE PK_UID= ? ''' % (x_egsa, y_egsa),  (myaddress , myID))
```

Comment: This is likely caused by incomplete initialisation of the mypoints table, or declaring it with something other than a POINT geometry with SRID 2100. Can you post the results of a command line query (use spatialite or sqlite binary) of ```SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name="mypoints";``` ?

Comment: Here is the result:`f_table_name:mypoints, f_geometry_column:the_geom, geometry_type:1,coord_dimension:2,srid:2100,spatial_index_enabled:0`